# oauth1, rsa-sha1, header params

Tags: python, oauth

I have been using requests-oauthlib, which do have rsa-sha1 signature algorithm, but there can't seem to be a way to add extra params to the authorization header, and if i do modify the header manually before making the request i get
"The request contains an incomplete or invalid oauth_signature."
because it had already created the oauth_signature when i have added the new oauth_body_hash to the authorization header.
i have pasted the code, the first call using oauth passes correctly, but the second one is giving the error.

any possible way to workaround this ? another library that has both options to add extra params and provide rsa-sha1 signature ?

```
oauth = OAuth1(
    consumer_key,
    signature_method='RSA-SHA1',
    signature_type='auth_header',
    rsa_key=key,
    callback_uri=callback_uri
)
oauth.client.realm = 'eWallet'
r = requests.post(url=request_token_url, auth=oauth)
credentials = parse_qs(r.content)
# end of request

# post shopingcart
root = ET.fromstring(shopping_cart_xml)
root.find('OAuthToken').text = credentials['oauth_token'][0]
xml = ET.tostring(root, encoding="us-ascii", method="xml")

sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
sha1.update(xml)
oauth_body_hash = sha1.digest()
oauth_body_hash = base64.b64encode(oauth_body_hash)
oauth.client.oauth_body_hash = oauth_body_hash

req = Request('POST', shopping_cart_url, data=xml, auth=oauth)
prepped = req.prepare()
auth_header = prepped.headers['Authorization'] + ', oauth_body_hash="%s"' %       (oauth_body_hash)

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml', 'Authorization': auth_header}
r = requests.post(url=shopping_cart_url, headers=headers, data=xml)
```